# Вывести 10 случайных символов из этой строки. C#

Tags: c#

```
Console.Write("\nВведите строку: ");              
string str = Console.ReadLine();
            
Random random = new Random();           // Создаем обьект класса рандом 
for (int i = 0; i < str.Length; i++)  
{
    string b = random.Next(i);    // Получаю через этот обьект случайные числа
    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Yellow;  
    Console.WriteLine(b); 
}
```

Я хочу вывести 10 случайных символов из строки что введу через консоль , но программа не запускается

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`string b = random.Next(i)` - попытка запихнуть число в строку, вам же вроде символы из строки нужны, а не числа, верно? Вот и берите из строки символы.

```
Console.Write("Введите строку: ");
string str = Console.ReadLine();

Random random = new Random();
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)  
{
    int index = random.Next(str.Length);
    string b = str[index].ToString();
    Console.WriteLine(b); 
}
```